# DispatcherTimer lag when UI idle

Tags: c#, wpf

Seems like *DispatcherTimer* has a strange lag when UI is idle - here is a small program to illustrate the problem:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="UIText" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="Number" Margin="10"/>
    <ToggleButton Margin="10" Content="Start" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Height="30"/>
    <CheckBox Name="UIJobBox" Margin="10" Content="UIJob"/>
</DockPanel>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int _counter = 0;
    private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle) { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25) };
    private Stopwatch _watch = new Stopwatch();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {_watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

        if (UIJobBox.IsChecked == true)
            UIText.Text = _counter++.ToString();
        _watch.Restart();
    }

    private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked == true)
            _timer.Start();
        else
            _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

When the checkbox is unchecked, there is nothing going on UI and stopwatch reports tick from 20-200 ms, if we check the checkbox (it will cause the UI to render the counter), the timings shown are about 20-35 ms. See the picture below:

[image: DispatcherTimerDifference]

This happens for all *DispatcherPriorities* lower than *Loaded*. As I understand *DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle* (or Background) should work fine when there is nothing heavy going on UI, therefore from where the lag comes from? Can anyone explain this?

---

Have done some more test - used .NET framework 4.7.1. Looks like the problem only occurs if program is run by Visual Studio (no matter Debug/Release) version. If the program is run separately the timings Idle/Busy are similar.

Comment: 2001 called and they want their _underscores back... Jk. This is something odd and after looking at it I can't say it makes any sense.  I'm tempted to put this together myself and explore it just out of curiosity.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Give a sign if you get any results, I also wonder if you get the same.

Comment: On my machine, I observe 25-70 ms for both cases, no difference. Maybe this depends on the .NET framework / runtime version. Have you tried a Release build with no debugger attached?

Comment: @dymanoid I've done some more tests. .NET framework 4.7.1, both Debug/Release configurations. However seems like the problem occurs only when VS is attached (no matter debug/release configuration) - if the program is run separately both timings for Idle/Busy are similar.